# Compare 2 List using Except

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have 2 `List<Animal>` which I would like to compare and find the difference between the 2 `List<Animal>` objects.

`Animal` object contains the following properties.

> Id
>
> Name
>
> Age

List `list1` has a count of 10 `Animal` objects in it, where as `list2` has another 10 `Animal` objects in it. In these 2 Lists there are 2 items (`Animal` objects that the same)

When I use the `Except` function, I was hoping that `remainingList` will contain Only the objects that aren't common between the 2 list. However, `remainingList` contains a copy of `list1` instead.

How can I solve this ?

```
 List<Animal> remainingList = list1.Except(list2).toListAsync();
```

Comment: I strongly suspect the problem is that `Animal` doesn't override `Equals`/`GetHashCode` or implement `IEquatable<Animal>`... so `Except` will only compare `Animal` *references* rather than the values of properties.

Comment: Is there a workaround for this. Rather than using `Except` can I use any other solution ?

Comment: @Illep - See first duplicated question - there is some explanation about passing an `IEqualityComparer` instead of overriding the methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to Override `Equal` and `GetHashCode` in your class. Something like this:

```
public class Animal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is Animal))
            return false;
        var p = (Animal)obj;
        return p.Id == Id && p.Name == Name && p.Age == Age;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}", Id, Name, Age).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Or with newer versions of C# you can:

```
public override int GetHashCode() => $"{Id}|{Name}|{Age}".GetHashCode();
```

Comment: I think it is strongly adviced that Immutable properties are used to calculate `GetHashCode` and `Equals`. Morever, may I suggest `Property.GetHashcode()^Property.GetHashcode()....` for hashcode?

Comment: I would also add a check for `if (obj == null) return false`. In any case where the right hand side is null, the instances are not equal.