# Perform "except" using particular columns

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, except

Consider 2 tables with the same schema:

```
var yesterday = new DataTable();
yesterday.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
yesterday.Columns.Add("part_number", typeof(string));
yesterday.Columns.Add("description", typeof(string));
yesterday.Columns.Add("comment", typeof(string));
yesterday.Columns.Add("information", typeof(string));
yesterday.Columns.Add("data", typeof(string));
var today = yesterday.Clone();
```

Add some data:

```
//yesterday data has 3 rows
yesterday.Rows.Add(1, "IVD_002", "IVD_002_RED", "Some comment", "Some information","Some data");
yesterday.Rows.Add(2, "IVD_003", "IVD_003_RED", "Some comment", "Some information", "Some data");
yesterday.Rows.Add(3, "IVD_004", "IVD_004_RED", "Some comment", "Some information", "Some data");

//today's data has the same 3 rows
today.Rows.Add(1, "IVD_002", "IVD_002_RED", "Some comment", "Some information", "Some data");
today.Rows.Add(2, "IVD_003", "IVD_003_RED", "Some comment", "Some information", "Some data");
today.Rows.Add(3, "IVD_004", "IVD_004_RED", "Some comment", "Some information", "Some data");
```

Let's add more data:

```
//The New Row:
//In the output table I expect to see only the following row. The "id" column is 5 whereas in previous records there is no row with id = 5, part_number = IVD_002, description = IVD_002_RED
today.Rows.Add(5, "IVD_002", "IVD_002_RED", "Some comment", "Some information", "Some data");

//Another New Row:
//I dont expect to see this row in the result table because we are doing except only on "id","part_number","description" columns
today.Rows.Add(1, "IVD_002", "IVD_002_RED", "ROSES ARE RED", "PEANUTS", "=)");
```

My goal is to get rows from "today" table except rows from "yesterday" table BUT comparing only columns "id","part_number","description".

Would really appreciate a pure LINQ solution, w/o loops.

Comment: You need something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52738791/2946329

Comment: This solution is intended to be used in UiPath, so I'm rather limited in what I can do with code. A LINQ-query would have been optimal.

Comment: @SalahAkbari This is a DataTable, not a list of custom objects.

Comment: @juharr I believe it is still possible, maybe something like this `IEqualityComparer<DataRow>` since the `DataTable` is an object still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `!Any`. I would prefer to convert the `yesterday` `DataTable` to a `HashSet` so you aren't constantly linearly scanning `yesterday` for matches, but I am not sure what limitations UiPath has.

```
var result = today.AsEnumerable().Where(t => !yesterday.AsEnumerable().Any(y => (y["id"].Equals(t["id"]) &&
                                                                                 y["part_number"].Equals(t["part_number"]) &&
                                                                                 y["description"].Equals(t["description"]))))
                                 .CopyToDataTable();
```

If you could use a `HashSet`, then you could do:

```
var yesterdayHash = yesterday.AsEnumerable().Select(y => new { id = (int)y["id"], partnum = y["part_number"].ToString(), desc = y["description"].ToString() }).ToHashSet();
var result2 = today.AsEnumerable().Where(t => !yesterdayHash.Contains(new { id = (int)t["id"], partnum = t["part_number"].ToString(), desc = t["description"].ToString() })).CopyToDataTable();
```

With a static class Cast helper for creating `Func` delegates that return anonymous types, you can create a lambda variable to hold the common key expression:

```
public static class To {
    public static Func<TResult> Func<TResult>(Func<TResult> func) => func;
    public static Func<T, TResult> Func<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> func) => func;
}

var selectorFn = To.Func((DataRow r) => new { id = r.Field<int>("id"), partnum = r.Field<string>("part_number"), desc = r.Field<string>("description") });
var yesterdayHash2 = yesterday.AsEnumerable().Select(selectorFn).ToHashSet();
var result3 = today.AsEnumerable().Where(t => !yesterdayHash2.Contains(selectorFn(t))).CopyToDataTable();
```

Note: I prefer using the `Field<>` extension method on `DataRow` to get strongly typed `DataTable` column values.

Comment: Now that's a real mage. Thanks you very much!

Comment: As for HashSet in UiPath, unfortunately it does not do well with anonymous types, so I'd have to stick to option #1

Answer (score 0):

I  think I got it. Is there a better way though?

```
var result = today.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r =>
        today.AsEnumerable()
            .Select(r =>
                new { id = r["id"].ToString(), part_number = r["part_number"].ToString(), description = r["description"].ToString() })
            .Except(yesterday.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(r =>
                    new { id = r["id"].ToString(), part_number = r["part_number"].ToString(), description = r["description"].ToString() }))
            .Contains(new { id = r["id"].ToString(), part_number = r["part_number"].ToString(), description = r["description"].ToString() }))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Is there a way to assign the "new" construct to a variable? An array of columns or smth? So I don't type the same 3 times

Comment: If you could create a lambda variable, you could do `var selectorFn = (DataTable r) =>
                new { id = r["id"].ToString(), part_number = r["part_number"].ToString(), description = r["description"].ToString() };` And then use it `today.AsEnumerable().Where(r => today.AsEnumerable().Select(selectorFn).Except(yesterday.AsEnumerable().Select(selectorFn)).Contains(selectorFn(r)).CopyToDataTable();`.

Comment: You would need a static cast helper for this to work. See My answer update.